# PBI DAX multiple if and Average exclude blank and zero

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a PBI DAX situation where I want to calculate the Average Working Days with 2 IF criteria....
(a) if the status = completed and (b) if the job state <> Cancelled

Also need the average calculation to exclude all blanks and zeros

Do I have to add a new column to calculate the working days i.e. (actual finish minus actual start) for each row first and then create the Measure?  Is there a way to do this altogether in the Measure?

thanks for sharing ideas

Answer (score 0):

```
Average_days = AVERAGEX(FILTER('Table', 'Table'[status]="Complete"), DATEDIFF(AVERAGE('Table'[start_date]), AVERAGE('Table'[end_date]), MINUTE)/(60*24))`
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.